# Clojure asynchronous access to shared resource

Tags: multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, clojure

I have a TCP socket connection in which I need to process `n` requests and `conj` each request and it's corresponding response to a vector for logging purposes. I need to transmit and receive via two asynchronous threads, where a `transmit` function is responsible for sending requests and a `receive` function is responsible for receiving responses from a server.

My understanding is that for asynchronous transmission, I need to use `agent`s in Clojure to accomplish this. However, I also need to ensure serial access to the vector, since both threads are trying to modify it at any given time.

I tried to get something working, but my agent ends up in a failed state after making a few requests and processing a few responses.

Below is the code showing what I am attempting to do. If anyone could give me some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
;; the shared resource

(def async-log (agent []))

;; I thought this needed to be synchronized for serial access, so I used 
;; dosync, but I am not sure if this is right. In any case, it doesn't 
;; seem to make a difference

(defn add-entry
  [coll entry]
  (dosync (conj coll entry)))

;; transmit function

(defn transmit
  [log writer socket request]
  (let [request   (request->String request socket)
        bytes-out (request->bytes request)
        length    (count bytes-out)]
    (.writeShort writer length)
    (.write writer bytes-out 0 length)
    (add-entry log request)))

;; Receive function

(defn receive
  [log reader socket]
  (let [length   (read-length reader)
        bytes-in (byte-array request/max-message-size)]
    (.read reader bytes-in 0 length)
    (add-entry log (to-string bytes-in))))

;; process each request, n times

(defn process-requests
  [request socket iters]
  (with-open [reader (DataInputStream. (.getInputStream socket))
              writer (DataOutputStream. (.getOutputStream socket))]
    (dotimes [x iters]
      (send-off async-log transmit writer socket request)
      (send-off async-log receive reader socket)
      (Thread/sleep 50))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that your dosync is not required there.

If the problem is that your agent is entering an error state, then you should be using the following functions:

[agent-error](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/agent-error) to investigate errors on an agent.

[restart-agent](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/restart-agent) to reset an agent's error state so that it can run again.

[set-error-handler!](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/set-error-handler!) to define the agent's behavior when it encounters errors.